# Try to increase root partition on dual system (ubuntu 22.04 + windows 10)

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I tried to increase root disk space on Ubuntu 22.04. I have:

1. dual system (The second OS is Windows 10.)
2. 17 Gb root disk
3. 28 Gb home
4. 4 Gb swap
5. 60 Gb free disk space

I found a lot of information how to do it, but unfortunately couldn't do it.
I booted from a live USB, started GParted and saw the following screen:

[image]

When I try to resize the partition it shows me that 0 disk space is available, and I don't know what to do next.

[image]

Comment: When you first installed Ubuntu you should have allowed at least 25 gig for the root partition. Also why all these partitions on such a small disk? Unless you have special needs for many partitions you should have let the install create what partitions it needed. That way you would not be here now. Having said that I recommend you delete the Ubuntu and reinstall from scratch letting the install do its job. Not being mean just pointing out where you most likely went wrong.

Comment: There are many good tutorials on the internet on how to resize partitions. You can not move space on the right all the way over to the left. You would need to move all the other partitions first. Very good chance you will lose all the info on the disk.

Comment: You must have followed very old, or very bad instructions, possibly both. Delete all of these partitions and reinstall Ubuntu with the default options. You don't need to partition this way and you've pigeonholed yourself into a situation where improper partitioning will leave your system constantly starving for free space

Answer (score 0):

If you don’t have much time invested in your existing installation then just reinstall, it’s the easiest solution. If you don’t want to do that you should be able to move your root partition to the unallocated space.

There are two ways to do this but backup any data you cannot afford to lose first.

I think you can copy/paste whole partitions with the live GParted environment. Just copy your root partition into the unallocated space and resize it to use all the space. I would also back the partition up by copying it to an external device first. You would also have to delete the original root partition and probably update grub. Be prepared to fix any booting issues that may arise and adjust your fstab file if necessary

Alternatively you can use the dd command to copy the data. First step would be to create a new partition in the unallocated space then use dd to copy. Be very careful with dd, if you point it’s output to the wrong place it will overwrite whatever is there. The same applies regarding removing the old partition and fixing any boot issues.

If you want to do this but are unsure of the details ask new questions

Good luck